# @Component @Scope("singleton") public class BootStrapper implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

Tags: spring, web-applications

I am trying to do a one time initialization of my webapp. I need a singleton for the ApplicationListener class, so I set the scope to Singleton, but it is creating multiple instances. This BootStrapper is not defined in any other xml config files. 
I know that the default scope is singleton, but had to add @Scope("singleton") because it was not a singleton. Even with this annotation, it still creates multiple instances.
Here is my ApplicationListener.

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class BootStrapper implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: The default scope is singleton

Comment: What is your problem? "but it is not working" is not a valid description of any (not named) problem!

Comment: How do you check that it create serveral instance of your bean?

Comment: Where do you put the breakpoint, in the constructor?

Comment: Do you have a web application?

Comment: Didn't see your questions. Yes, I have a web application. I guess the problem is due to running Tomcat on a multicore processor and getting one spring container for each core. I am not sure if each core gets its own spring container.

Comment: If you have ONE Tomcat instance, and did not do any hack to create multiple instances, then you should have only one spring context (even on a multi core processor)

Answer (score 5):

To have a callback that is invoked after the bean is initialized, use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html).

```
@Component
public class BootStrapper() {

     @PostConstruct
     public void doSomething() {
          System.out.println("I am initalized!");
     }
}
```

Comment: You are probably referring to javax.annotation.PostConstruct (not PostCreate). Also, a return type should be added to the "doSomething" method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@Configuration
public class TestService
{
  private Properties properties;

  @Bean
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
  public Properties getAppProperties()
  {
    try
    {
        if (properties == null)
        {
          properties = ServiceUtils.loadProperties();
        }
     return properties;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      LOGGER.logCaughtException("Exception Occured while loading App Properties.", e);
    }
  }
}
```